# Feign triggers fallback but the response status is 200

Tags: feign, circuit-breaker

My app uses zookeeper that manager cluster.

[image: 1]

Here is the console log, I checked the official documentation, but I didn't find a relevant issue.
It's out time exception,but I set the timeout of the circuit breaker to 5s and still get the timeout exception.

Can you help me?